# How to print something only on he first item when parsing using ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs

So I have a `ng-repeat` which I am parsing through an array `propRentDetail`. It prints out some divs with the property name and its rent. 
I have also used `orderBy : '-trent'`, so that it shows the property first which has the highest rent and goes down. Now, I have an up arrow icon from fontAwesome and I was trying to show that only with the first property div (i.e. the one with the highest rent). So how do I show something only for the first item?

```html
<div ng-repeat = "summ in propRentDetail | orderBy: '-trent'">
    <p>{{ summ.propname }}</p>
    <p>{{ summ.proprent }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside `ng-repeat`, AngularJS expose a variable named `$first`, its value is type boolean which refers if the item is first on the list.

```html
<div ng-repeat = "summ in propRentDetail | orderBy: '-trent'">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow" ng-if="$first"></i>
    <p>{{ summ.propname }}</p>
    <p>{{ summ.proprent }}</p>
</div>
```

You can also use `$index` if you want

```html
<div ng-repeat = "summ in propRentDetail | orderBy: '-trent'">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow" ng-if="$index === 0"></i>
    <p>{{ summ.propname }}</p>
    <p>{{ summ.proprent }}</p>
</div>
```

Other variables available inside `ng-repeat`:

- `$last`
- `$even`
- `$odd`

Answer (score 3):

Use `$first` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat = "summ in propRentDetail | orderBy: '-trent'">
    <div ng-if="$first">icon</div>
    <p>{{ summ.propname }}</p>
    <p>{{ summ.proprent }}</p>
</div>
```